# Access React state from outside script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make app, that uses React and also js script with loop, body of `index.html` looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script>init();</script>
</body>
```

I need to pass state updates to running js script, but have no idea how. Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"I need to pass state updates to running js script"* Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @FelixKling `init()` -- starts function that creates shader program and runs loop to pass updated arguments to it and redraw canvas. Part of app, that uses React, collects user input and passes it to shader program. Anyway, i already found solution -- not sure if optimal -- use global window object to track state changes.